# Basic rails 3 routes and unknown routes (including wildcards)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rails-routing

I've been reading about routing in Rails 3 and have been unsuccessful in achieving what I need.  Still fairly new to routes in Rails 3 so I may simply be overlooking things or overcomplicating it.

This is what I'm looking to achieve:

`website/foo` routes to the `foo` controller, `index` action

`website/foo/index` routes to the `foo` controller, `index` action

`website/foo/bar` routes to the `foo` controller, `bar` action

`website/foo/random` routes to the `foo` controller, `index` action

`website/foo/bar/rondom` routes to the `foo` controller, `bar` action

where "random" can be any text, numbers, paths (/new/x/w/y/23) or whatever.

I tried using both `match`, and `resources` with `collection` and while it handled the base case, it did not handle "random".

I'm also looking for the respective named path, should that be specified or will it be generated?

Comment: ```rake routes``` will show you named routes that exist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

```
foo/bar/*additional => "foo#bar"
```

Examples:

```
website/foo/bar/random # params[:additional] = "random"
website/foo/bar/random/2 # params[:additional] = "random/2"
website/foo/bar/random/and/more/1/random/stuff/ # params[:additional] = "random/and/more/1/random/stuff/"
```

Comment: I can't really do much with this comment.  Please provide your routes.rb file and I'll take a look.

Comment: I was trying this but got an error.    
`match 'foo/*other' => 'foo#index', :as => 'foo#index'`  
`match 'foo/bar/*other' => "foo#bar', :as => 'foo#bar'`  
  
gives the error:  
  
`ActionController::RoutingError Exception: /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-3.0.9/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:425:in 'raise_routing_error': No route matches {:controller=>"foo"}`  
  
although the `foo` controller exists

Comment: @baash05 - While it does link to outside info, it also provides a pretty clear example of the usage. I also can't help but notice you were less vigilant with other answers here that also link to outside info.

Answer (score 1):

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html contains heaps of really useful information, especially the section on [route globbing](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#route-globbing).

To match exactly what you defined above you could:

```
# config/routes.rb
namespace :website do
  match 'foo'             => 'foo#index'
  match 'foo/index'       => 'foo#index'
  match 'foo/bar'         => 'foo#bar'
  match 'foo/*random'     => 'foo#index' # params[:random] will contain "hello/world" if the URL is /website/foo/hello/world
  match 'foo/bar/*random' => 'foo#bar'
end
```

You can use the `:as` option to specify a named route, e.g.

```
match 'foo' => 'foo#index', as: 'foo' # helper would be website_foo_path
```